# NSData crashes application with ARC

Tags: unit-testing, ios5, nsdata

When doing this in a class in my mainbundle:

```
  NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlLowerCase]; (or file, doesn't matter)
```

Everything works just FINE.

Doing the EXACT same in my testbundle crashes xcode without an error.

I'm totally flabbergasted. How could this be caused ?